# python unittest mocking / patching

Tags: python, mocking

Not wanting to test manually my code, I'm trying to write a test which mocks/patches one of my dependencies (PyInquirer is a pretty neat package which handles the CLI for me - question dicts in, answer dicts out).

However, being very new to Python, I'm having difficulties with mocking that dependency. Here's the code I'm testing:

```
from PyInquirer import prompt


class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        # this line is asking the user for inpit, and that's what I want to mock.
        a = prompt({'name': 'q',
                    'type': 'input',
                    'message': 'well, foo'})
        print("f is", f)
        return a
```

And this is the test:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from Foo import Foo


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('PyInquirer.prompt', return_value=24)
    def test_bar(self):
        f = Foo()
        a = f.bar()
        assert a == 24


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(the real code is obviously more complicated, but this is the essence of the problem). Which manifests itself as:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
TypeError: test_bar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm quite confused.

If I omit the patch decorator, the invocation fails with an expected assertion error - the dictionary produced by prompt isn't equal to 24. But if I do provide the decorator, I get the argument mismatch above. And indeed the last line in the stacktrace does show the function "func", which I presume is what the decorator was applied to, is invoked with two arguments... but... why? Can't be the essence of a problem? That only functions with arity of two can be thus patched =)

Comment: `@patch` adds an extra argument, the mock object, to the function it's decorating. Also note that you patch where something is imported *to*, not *from*. Both of these things are covered in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: Thank you sir. My patch is added the test - which is the place  where the code under testing is executed in the context.. of testing. What other place can I place it in?! My code? The third-party code I am trying to mock? Pray tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class uses the name `Foo.prompt` (because of how you import it), so *that's* what you need to patch.

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('Foo.prompt', return_value=24)
    def test_bar(self, mock_prompt):
        f = Foo()
        a = f.bar()
        assert a == 24
```

You also need to add a parameter to `test_bar` to receive the patched object, whether or not you plan to use it. If you don't want to do that,
you can move the call to `patch` inside the method, using it with a `with` statement.

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with patch('Foo.prompt', return_value=24):
            f = Foo()
            a = f.bar()
            assert a == 24
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! This is very different from the JVM mocking which I am used to; especially the Foo.prompt part.

Comment: @alexakarpov. Yea another long time jvm guy and i don't understand python mocks at all

Comment: They aren't really mocks at all (despite being implemented in the `mock` module). They are patching *names*, which means you have to know which name is being patched, which requires you to understand how name lookup occurs in Python. `Foo` uses the name `prompt` defined in its own module-global scope, which is why you need to patch `Foo.prompt` rather than `PyInquirer.prompt`. If `Foo` used `import PyInquirer; ... PyInquirer.prompt`, then patching `PyInquirer.prompt` would be correct.